# How to read xml datetime in sql

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a stored procedure which is receiving xml parameter now xml contain date and time field

Here is the sample of my xml which is passed as parameter to the stored procedure. I am using SQL Server 2005

```
 <transdetails>
  <_x005B_Sheet1_x0024__x005D_>
    <Date_of_transaction>2011-07-29T13:47:34+05:00</Date_of_transaction>
    <Type_of_the_transaction>card</Type_of_the_transaction>
    <Card_number>7000460000451470</Card_number>
    <Total_quantity>27.81</Total_quantity>
    <Total_amount>2419.75</Total_amount>
    <Name_of_Retail_Outlet>MIDWAY PETROLEUM SERVICES</Name_of_Retail_Outlet>
    <Product_Purchased>PETROL</Product_Purchased>
  </_x005B_Sheet1_x0024__x005D_>
<transdetails>
```

Here is the stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_getexceldata]
    @transdetails xml 
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SET ARITHABORT ON
BEGIN
    DECLARE @XML AS XML

    DECLARE @DestinationTemp TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
                                    Date_of_transaction VARCHAR,
                                    Type_of_the_transaction nvarchar(255),
                                    Card_number nvarchar(255),
                                    Total_quantity float,
                                    Total_amount float, 
                                    Name_of_Retail_Outlet nvarchar(255),
                                    Product_Purchased nvarchar(255)
                                   )

    SET @XML = @transdetails

    INSERT INTO @DestinationTemp(Date_of_transaction, Type_of_the_transaction, Card_number, Total_quantity, Total_amount, Name_of_Retail_Outlet, Product_Purchased)
        SELECT
            x.d.query('./Date_of_transaction').value('.' , 'DateTime')  Date_of_transaction,
            x.d.query('./Type_of_the_transaction').value('.', 'nvarchar(255)') Type_of_the_transaction,
            x.d.query('./Card_number').value('.', 'nvarchar(255)')  Card_number,
            x.d.query('./Total_quantity').value('.' ,'float')  Total_quantity,
            x.d.query('./Total_amount').value('.' , 'float')  Total_amount,
            x.d.query('./Name_of_Retail_Outlet').value('.' ,'nvarchar(255)')  Name_of_Retail_Outlet,
            x.d.query('./Product_Purchased').value('.', 'nvarchar(255)')  Product_Purchased
        FROM
            @XML.nodes('transdetails//_x005B_Sheet1_x0024__x005D_')  x(d)

    SELECT * FROM @DestinationTemp
```

Now I get an error when trying to convert `Date_of_transaction` to datetime if I try to set the value initially as varchar then it returns integer value for example if I have date

```
2011-07-29T13:47:34+05:00
```

it will return me 2...please any help?

Answer (score 3):

Your inserting into a column defined as `Date_of_transaction VARCHAR` so it will *truncate* to 1 character as there is no scale specified, hence the `2`.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server 2005 does not handle the timezone part of your datetime value.

One option for you could be to use [substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178063.aspx) to get the datetime without the timezone.

```
x.d.query('./Date_of_transaction').value('substring(., 1, 19)' , 'DateTime')
```

The resulting value in your sample is `2011-07-29 13:47:34.000`.

In SQL Server 2008 your query would work just fine **but** the value returned would be `2011-07-29 08:47:34.000` instead because it uses the time zone value.

BTW: You should change the data type of `Date_of_transaction` to `DateTime` in `@DestinationTemp`.